# How does OpenID Connect deal with service chains?

Tags: security, jwt, openid-connect

### Background

Say I have an application to create shipments.  A user sits down in front of that application and loads the page.  They are then redirected to the IDP to login.  The flow I use is the Authorization Code flow.  This involves a Client ID and Client Secret.  The IDP can take those values along with the User's Credentials and do the login.

After the login, the application gets an `id_token` that lets the application know who the user is (authentication).

The application then needs to call a service (we can call it Service 1).  The application can pass the `id_token` to Service 1 as a JWT bearer token.

Service 1 gets the JWT and can use the signature on it (with the IDP's public key) to verify that the JWT in fact came from an IDP that it trusts.

### Problem

This is all great and works just fine.  But now Service 1 needs to call Service 2 to fulfill the Shipment Application's request.

This is where things get confusing for me.  Service 1 has its own Client ID and Client Secret. And it can get a "Client Credentials" token.  But Service 2 needs to know the user that is making the request and a Client Credentials token does not have any user information in it.

The `Authorization: Bearer` header only allows for one token.  But I need space for two:

- If I only pass the User's JWT, my JWT looks like the call came directly from the Shipment Application to service 2.  (It may be that Service 2 should not even be called directly from the Shipment Application.)
- But if I pass only the Client Credentials token of Service 1, then Service 2 is not going to get the user's information.

Either way Service 2 is not going to be happy.

### Question

**Does OpenID Connect have a way to merge two tokens?  Or some other way to allow for chains of service calls to work?**

NOTE: I currently am passing both.  One in the `Authorization: Bearer` header and one in a custom header.  But because this is not part of the OpenID Connect protocol, it is causing issues when working with 3rd party tools (like OpenAPI (aka Swagger)).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at delegated tokens pattern to issue a new token for Service1 to Service communication.

See:

- https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/delegation-tokens
- https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Delegation-Patterns-for-OAuth-20